# Sub is ending prematurely?

Tags: vb.net

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To _rows.Count
        If (_rows(i).LeftOffset > largestOffset) Then
            largestOffset = _rows(i).LeftOffset
        End If
    Next i

    For i As Integer = 0 To _rows.Count
```

This code is never getting to the second for, I can put a breakpoint on the End If in there and it triggers for _rows.Count like it should, but then if there's a breakpoint on the second for or anything after it it's never reached.  There's no error message, the program doesn't freeze or anything and it behaves exactly as if I had done:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To _rows.Count
        If (_rows(i).LeftOffset > largestOffset) Then
            largestOffset = _rows(i).LeftOffset
        End If
    Next i

    Return

    For i As Integer = 0 To _rows.Count
```

Comment: you tried _rows.count -1?  an exception might be throw as you're above the higher bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be _rows.Count-1 as the upper bound.  The last time round the loop will fail with an IndexOutOfRangeException.

I have found that in a few places in VB.net, especially in Form_Load, errors are not shown up by the debugger, and the Sub just exits silently, and the program continues.  A try...catch block around it will catch an exception however.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it was just exiting, I guess it's a bug (or feature) of the debugger.

Comment: I don't think it's just the debugger -I think it also applies at runtime, that errors here will not propagate out to any other exception handler.  I'm now in the habit of adding a try...catch around then entire of the Form_Load of any complex form, even if all it does is show the exception in a message box.  It can be a real head-scratcher when part of the initialisation hasn't run and then things are crashing later in the form code.